# how to customize zendesk chat message design ? For Android

Tags: java, android, xml, chat, zendesk-api

Is there a way to customize chat messages design for zendesk android sdk ?

By default their design is too simple, I want to add circular images some shadows etc

So is there a way to achieve this ?

They also have CHAT API but i don't have any clue how to use that to customize chat message design

In short I want to control the whole chat design on my own

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the android sdk documentation link

https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android-chat-sdk/sessionapi

Just use the listeners for chat log and connection and use the callbacks to create an arraylist and pass it to your adapter

That's how i was able to override the chat functionality of zendesk chat for android